# upgrading drbd8 to drbd9

Tags: upgrade

Bonjour,

We have 3 identical nodes running drbd version: 8.4.7 (api:1/proto:86-101) and upgrade to drbd9 is on the menu.

Is it safe to have drbd8 running alongside with drbd9? at least during upgrade process.

Thanks!

--- system config (identical nodes)

- Ubuntu server 18.04 (end of life) upgrading to Ubuntu 20
- HD= 2x2TBytes per node
- RAM= 32GBytes
- drbd version: 8.4.7 (api:1/proto:86-101) -- srcversion: 7FA2FF168828B1B272D3F92

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

a drbd node on 8.4 can replicate to a node with drbd 9.0 , BUT NOT THE OPPOSITE

The process  is well documentated on the website of linbit ( creator of drbd ) .

https://www.linbit.com/drbd-user-guide/drbd-guide-9_0-en/#s-upgrading-drbd

Comment: I have indeed checked that guide on their website but is it also for those not having subscription?
They also do not mention backup or rollback process, does that mean there is no risk?